# Remove HTML tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new on jQuery. I want to remove HTML tag only, not its content. The following is my code

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Personal Loans</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Secured Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Unsecured Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bad Credit Loans</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Debt Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Debt Consolidation Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Credit Card Debt Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">IVAs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Payday Loans</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Text Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Short Term Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cash Loan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Same Day Loan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Instant Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quick Loan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cash Advances</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fast Loan</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Car Loan</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mortgage</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove the nested `<ul>` only, but not its children `<li>`. Is this possible in jQuery? Please help me.

Comment: It's not possible since `li` *must* be inside `ul` or other list tag. It will be possible if you replace `li` with, for example, `div`.

Comment: What end-result are you hoping for? An `li` is only a valid child of a `ul` or `ol`, so what you're asking becomes: 'how can I use JavaScript to create invalid HTML?' Which is, *at best*, unwise.

Comment: actually i want to use this same code on different places on website with different style so that i want to remove these nested '<ul>' on run time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put an `li` inside another `li`. What you can do, though, is move the `li` elements from within the `ul` and put them just after the `li` that used to contain the `ul`. Something along these lines:

```
$("ul > li ul").each(function() {
    var $ul = $(this);
    $ul.children().insertAfter($ul.parent());
    $ul.remove();
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ipaduj/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ipaduj/1/edit)

Comment: @user1849368: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score -1):

You could call the [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method on your list item.

This will remove the `ul` element and reparent the `li` element (and its siblings, if any) under the `ul` element.

Comment: *"This will remove the 'ul' element and reparent the 'li' element (and its siblings, if any) under the 'ul' element."* No, it will remove the `ul` and attempt to put its `li` elements *within* the `li` that used to contain the `ul`. The browser *may* then try its best to put up with the invalid DOM structure, but it's better not to create invalid DOM structures in the first place.